# Почему не обновляются данные парсинга после нажатия кнопки в боте телеграмм

Tags: python, telegram-bot

написал парсер для получения данных о погоде, вычленил нужные данные, подключил это все дело к боту. При первом запуске данные передаются, но при повторных нажатиях кнопки "Узнать погоду", данные остаются старые, то есть функция как будто не выполняется. Что я сделал неверно и как это поправить?

```
import telebot
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from telebot import types

    введите сюда код

url = 'https://pogoda.mail.ru/prognoz/moskva/'

response = requests.get(url)

def weather(url):
 bs = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")

 temp = bs.find('div', 'information__content__temperature').text.strip()
 city = bs.find('h1', 'information__header__left__place__city').text.strip()
 date = bs.find('div', 'information__header__left__date').text.strip()
 react = bs.find('div', 'information__content__additional__item').text.strip()
 s = bs.find('div', 'information__content__additional information__content__additional_first').text.strip()
 result = f'{city}: {temp}, {react}, {s}, {date}'
 return result

res = weather(url)

bot = telebot.TeleBot('5602472525:AAGk8vUDt80xAMzWiXDdPuGgGD111sf_q5cjCuo')
@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def start(message, res=False):
 markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
 btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("Узнать погоду")
 markup.add(btn1)
 bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text='Жми кнопку'.format(message.from_user), reply_markup=markup)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def func(message):
    if(message.text == "Узнать погоду"):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, res)

bot.polling()
```

Comment: Перенесите запрос response = requests.get(url) в функцию def weather(url). Уберите из параметров передающихся в функцию url, а url = 'https://pogoda.mail.ru/prognoz/moskva/' так же перенесите в функцию.

Answer (score 0):

У вас запрос данных находиться за пределами функции парсинга данных о погоде. Перенесите запрос в функцию, а также параметр url. Примерно это будет выглядеть так:

```
def weather():
    response = requests.get('https://pogoda.mail.ru/prognoz/moskva/')
    bs = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")

    temp = bs.find('div', 'information__content__temperature').text.strip()
    city = bs.find('h1', 'information__header__left__place__city').text.strip()
    date = bs.find('div', 'information__header__left__date').text.strip()
    react = bs.find('div', 'information__content__additional__item').text.strip(
    s = bs.find('div', 'information__content__additional information__content__additional_first').text.strip(
    result = f'{city}: {temp}, {react}, {s}, {date}'
    return result
```

Если вы запрос погоды будете делать в другом городе, тогда url надо будет делать не постоянным, а передавать в функцию из бота. То есть, вернуть url:

```
def weather(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
```